# How the understand the "too ... to" structure?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

It is easy to understand when someone says:

> The box is too heavy to carry.

But the usage of "*too … to*" structure in "You cannot be too careful to go across the road" is weird for me, though I know what it means.

Can anyone explain to me how to understand the real logic behind the usage of "*too … to*" pattern in the latter case?

Comment: The ***too* `Adj/Adv` *to* `VP`** construction is equivalent to ***so* `Adj/Adv` *that* `Not Possible S`**; i.e, _The box is too heavy to lift_ means _The box is so heavy that it's not possible to lift it_. The subject of the infinitive is deleted and may be indefinite; deletion destroys information. Compare _The bomb is too wet to carry_ vs _The bomb is too wet to go off_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question. Actually, in certain contexts you *can* say things like that...

> *"Hey! You wanna come [bungee-jumping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bungee_jumping) this weekend?"
>
>    "No way! It's far too dangerous!"
>
>    "I'm much too careful to trust my life to a bit of elastic cord!"
>
>    "Wimp! You're so careful you wouldn't cross the road without the [lollipop lady](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_guard) to hold your hand!"*

Grammatically there's nothing wrong there. It's just that with the particular activity *being careful* and infinitive verbs, we're more used to constructions like...

> 1: *I'm always careful to avoid judging a book by its cover*.
>    2: *The burglar was careful to avoid leaving any fingerprints.*
>    3: *The burglar was too careful to leave any fingerprints.*

Notice how in #3, *leave any fingerprints* appears syntactically identical to OP's *go across the road*. But actually, there's a big difference. We can recast OP's example into

> *You can't be too careful [when] **going** across the road*.
>    *(The more careful you are, the better. No matter how careful you are, you can't be **too careful**)*

But with my example #3, we simply can't introduce the gerund like that...

> 3a: **The burglar couldn't be too careful leaving any fingerprints.*

...where I don't think any amount of "contrived context" would make #3a acceptable to native speakers. The difference is down to semantics...

> *to go/going across the road* - is **normally** an activity that can be done with more or less carefulness.
>    *to leave/leaving fingerprints* - is a "careless" activity (doing it at all indicates lack of carefulness).

I'll leave it to wiser heads than mine to explain exactly why a "contrived context" would be (just) possible in #3a, if I didn't have the word ***any*** (but becomes totally impossible when it *is* present).

---

TL;DR: OP happens to have chosen a specific activity *(being careful [**when**] crossing the road)* that conflicts with the normal context where we talk about being ***too*** careful (**to** take risks).

Answer (score 2):

Your second example seems weird to you because it *is* weird. Something like *You can't be too careful while crossing the road* would be more idiomatic. (Or, interpreting your sentence differently, *You can't be careful to the degree that you avoid crossing roads entirely.*)

That said, I can think of logical examples in which this structure could be used. An exasperated parent might say to a child, for instance, *You can't be too sick to go to school* or *You can't be too tired to brush your teeth.*

The clearest way to parse these might be *You can't be so sick that you're unable go to school* or *You can't be so tired that you're unable to brush your teeth*.

*Too* emphasizes the degree of the relevant adjective, much like *so*.